# Upgrade manager wants me to do a partial upgrade

Tags: update-manager

So here is my story...

I was doing upgrades to ubuntu the other day, and the power went out right in the middle of the upgrade, so now when I try to do upgrades it keeps asking me if I want to do a partial upgrade. I have heard this is bad and should be avoided, I also know there is a way to fix this via the command line, but I can't remember how, nor can I find anything on the internet.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like `sudo dpkg --configure -a` is the magical command.

Here is the `dpkg` man page’s explanation of the `--configure -a` options:

> `--configure` *package*...|`-a`|`--pending`
>
> Configure a package which has been unpacked but not yet configured. If `-a` or `--pending` is given […], all unpacked but unconfigured packages are configured.
>
> […]
>
> Configuring consists of the following steps:
>
> 1. Unpack the conffiles, and at the same time back up the old conffiles, so that they can be restored if something goes wrong.
> 2. Run *postinst* script, if provided by the package.

Comment: usually that fixes it all, if it doesn't try firing up synaptic, or do sudo apt-get install aptitude, and then sudo aptitude (should have a gtk gui with Maverick). aptitude is usually better at finding/fixing the problems.

Comment: Doesn't have noticeable effects on my box.
Still offers a partial upgrade.

Answer (score 23):

I'd suggest trying this:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
```

Solved the issue for me, probably will work for you as well.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. What I did was, obtain the list of packages from `sudo apt-get upgrade`. In my case:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Then I installed the "not upgraded" packages with `sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic` and problem solved.

Comment: You could also have done `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

partial upgrade means that something went wrong with an installation or update. I started receiving this partial upgrade prompt after a botched Mplayer media player installation. I removed the software and via the purge command got rid of everything associated with Mplayer media player.
This also interfered with some plugins i had installed for gstreamer and VLC. I reinstalled what i had lost and the partial upgrade prompts quit showing up.
I suggest you find out what happened especially with a recent installation of a PPA

Answer (score -1):

you can try `sudo apt-get update` through this files will be updated.
and then you can upgrade through terminal by typing `sudo do-release-upgrade` when it will ask
Installing the upgrade can take several hours. Once the download has 
finished, the process cannot be canceled.
then press 'Y' thats all.