# Partial Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, partial-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrade manager wants me to do a partial upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16494/upgrade-manager-wants-me-to-do-a-partial-upgrade)

I recently attempted to upgrade my 11.04 to 11.10, but the upgrade failed. Now whenever I open the update-manager it asks to do a partial upgrade. Is there a way to get it to upgrade or atleast stop it from asking about the partial upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

Try opening a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install
```

This should fix any previously interrupted update process and, if possible, continue with updating.

**NEW IDEA:**

What happens if you try:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Still asking to do a partial upgrade.

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: I get this:
"E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'util-linux'. Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)"