# How to interpret this screenshot error for gnome-screenshot?

Tags: gnome, screenshot

This is the error when I type gnome-screenshot:

```
$ gnome-screenshot
** DEBUG: The GetProfileForWindow request failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
```

I installed gnome-color-manager, but that didn't fix the problem (I still can't take screenshots, and still get this error).  All the search results I saw recommended changing xorg.conf, but I only have an xorg.conf.failsafe file, not an xorg.conf file.

Comment: After installing gnome-color-manager, the error remains as:  ** DEBUG: The GetProfileForWindow request failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program /usr/bin/gcm-session: Success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been [reported](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=660272) in the GNOME Bugzilla bug tracking system.

> D-Bus allows programs to register with it in order to offer services.
>   It also allows client programs to check for the availability of
>   services.

The service is either *not known* for the DBus backend or it cannot be run for *security* reasons.

You can try to run the tool as root and see if it works.

Source:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus)
- [Launchpad Bug #400200](https://bugs.launchpad.net/checkbox/+bug/400200)

Comment: Hmm, cool.  Well, that's helpful, but I'm afraid that leaves me more confused.  =)  The program that caused this was gnome-screenshot, which worked until yesterday, so I know it should be a known service, right?

Comment: Well, I could not guess from the question, but sure. If it worked yesterday I'd consider a few things. You might have updated packages that broke the tool, or the Update Manager installed something, you can check the logs.

Comment: Just tested myself, I have got the same *debug* message, but the screenshot tool works. Do you have any related error message in `~/.xsession-errors`?

Comment: Yeah, that file has zillions of errors.  Most concerning "org.ayatana.bamf.view"  I know the screenshot is kind of working because it makes a sound, and gives me an image composed of a black page---it's just that it's only a black page, rather than what's on the screen.  Anyway, in a sea of errors, which would you recommend I look for that might be best to explore getting a picture taken?

Comment: Apart from renaming and creating an empty file here is a simple way: open terminal and type `tail -f ~/.xsession-errors`. Then press Enter a few times to separate previous entries. Now open a new terminal window and run gnome-screensot. Your previous terminal window will be updated with error messages that should be related to the problem. Press CTRL+C to stop the tail program. Here is my output for a comparison: http://pastie.org/2771817

Comment: Cool, thanks!  OK, well, it looks like my problem with screenshots stems from an inappropriate version of libglib.  I have 2.31.0 installed, and should have 2.30.0.  Since most packages on my installation depend on it, I probably won't be downgrading to fix this, as that would remove too many pieces to keep track of reinstalling, and will just live without screenshots.  =(  Thanks though!  This was what I needed to diagnose this

Comment: I am very glad that I could help you!

Comment: I think this approach was the best way to address my question, so I'm selecting as the answer, and I want to point others looking to fully resolve this issue to a new question I raised, here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73092/how-to-downgrade-libglib2-11-10-comparing-two-options

Comment: I had kind of put off resolving this for awhile, but recently needed screenshots again.  This is accurately diagnosed, I think, but I'm still unsure how to solve it.

Comment: As I'm reading back the conversation, it seems to me that you had a library version mismatch problem. Since downgrade was not an option, a few others are: recompile from source with the new binding (if possible), wait for Precise and install a fresh system, install a version that depends on the newer library, (or use an alternative screenshot application).

Comment: Interesting---so I downgraded the libraries, and I also ran gnome-screenshot as root, and it looks like I still the same error message: `(gnome-screenshot:916): DEBUG: The GetProfileForWindow request failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program /usr/bin/gcm-session: Success
`

Comment: Might also be related to this question, actually: http://askubuntu.com/questions/104348/how-to-fix-this-gdbus-error