# Wifi can't connect before wired.  How to diagnose what could be going wrong (which logs, etc)?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, networking, diagnostic

I think this is a problem related to [another I've had](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73092/how-to-downgrade-libglib2-11-10-comparing-two-options), but here's the first situation:

- When I boot up and connect to wireless, I am told I connect to my wireless network.
- However, I am unable to actually connect to the internet.  (Pages time out and say not connected.)

In the second situation
- When I boot up and connect via eth, my connection is fine
- I can then simultaneously connect to wireless.
- After removing the ethernet connection, I have wireless that works fine and keeps my connection.

Not sure what the root mechanism that's causing this problem is, but I suspect it's related to xorg and libglib2 problems I experienced and am resolving elsewhere.  However, to confirm my hunches, what log file should I be looking at to even identify why this is happening?  I'm gunning with this question for a list of places that I should look to diagnose this crazy problem, given that there is a behavior that works differently depending on order of connection.

(One other note, I know this has worked in the recent past, so it's not an issue of the wireless card itself.)

**UPDATE** Mobile broadband has the same problem.  Does not work unless I first connect to wired connection and simultaneously connect to broadband before removing wired connection.  Help, please!

**UPDATE 2** Forget diagnosis, can someone fix this please?  I've been in windows for a week because I can't use wifi!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/log/syslog` should give you some information about what's going on with your connections, you may also find some information in `/var/log/kernel`.