# Cannot open PNG files with imageviewer

Tags: png, image-viewers, eog

When I try to open PNG files, I double click them, then nothing happens.  I have to go to "Open with" and select F-spot photoviewer to view PNG files.

This is eog, eye of gnome, correct?  How can I troubleshoot the default image viewer?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your setup? For example, is this a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10, or an upgrade? Also, have you considered [filing a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)?

Comment: It's an upgrade from 11.04.  But you're right, it looks like a widely reported, and widely unfixed bug.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eog/+bug/880227 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eog/+bug/881581 https://lists.launchpad.net/desktop-packages/msg40805.html

Comment: Hey guys, can I ask why this is off-topic?  Asking this really and chasing down the error messages really did help me find the solution to my problem.

Comment: Known bugs are generally regarded to be offtopic on AskUbuntu, and we have them closed once we know a proper report on Launchpad exists. For more information, see the [faq].

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Thanks, @WarriorIng64 . I didn't know the rules.  But this process of tracking down the official bug based on the error was very helpful for me, thanks to you and jedijf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on the Glib-GIO-CRITICAL issue, I googled around a little and found it actually was a known issue with libglib.  I had another outstanding problem with that, and question on askubuntu.  I went ahead with rolling back a version, and the problem was corrected.  Details for what was rolled back are here:

[How do I downgrade libglib2? (from glib 2.31 to 2.30?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73092/how-do-i-downgrade-libglib2-from-glib-2-31-to-2-30/112101#112101)

Answer (score 0):

Try opening from command line and see if that gives output.

```
eog /path/to/something.png
```

Comment: `user@machine:~/Desktop$ /usr/bin/eog file.png

 
GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: Timeout was reached`