# How to fix this GDBus error?

Tags: 11.10, dbus

After running a system update I got this error when I wanted to save a screen shot to my desktop:

Impossible to save the screenshot to file:///home/tinuz/Pictures.
 Error was

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildSignaled: Process /usr/bin/nautilus received signal 6.
 Please choose another location and retry.
```

It tells me to save it to another location but when saving to another location I get the same error message. Please let me know how to fix the problem.

Thanks in advance tinuz

Just got home and here is the output:

`tinuz@PC1-1110:~$ id; ls -ld /home/tinuz/Pictures; ls -ld /home/tinuz; ls -ld /home`

```
uid=1000(tinuz) gid=1000(tinuz) groups=1000(tinuz),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),118(admin),124(sambashare)
drwxr-xr-x 4 tinuz tinuz 4096 2012-02-14 21:25 /home/tinuz/Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 49 tinuz tinuz 4096 2012-02-15 18:24 /home/tinuz
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2012-01-29 22:07 /home
tinuz@PC1-1110:~$
```

Comment: (1) Edit your question and provide the output of these commands. They'll show your username, groups and folder permissions: `id; ls -ld /home/tinuz/Pictures; ls -ld /home/tinuz; ls -ld /home` (2) Did you try some other folder?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...

I did try to save to another folder/location and still have the same error message. I can save files but the problem only occurs when i want to save a screen shot.

I have to try the command line when i'm back home and will let you know the output.

Comment: Try creating a new user. If it works there, it's either some file permissions problem or a configuration option in your home folder (hidden files).

Comment: By the way, are you using gnome/unity/ubuntu, xfce/Xubuntu or lxde/Lubuntu?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and creating a new user didn't work and the problem isn't solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments above, sounds like a program (file permissions or otherwise) problem. Unfortunately, in this case, I would backup my important data and just reinstall the root (/) partition.

If you enabled any PPA or other third-party repositories, please don't, they're not all safe, unless you're 100% sure they work. Sometimes they exist in order to test packages.

Alternatively, you can always:

1. use the command `import` from package `imagemagick`
2. install `gimp` and from the menu File > Create > Screenshot

Comment: The only way to save the screen shot is by making it, copy it to clipboard and then open gimp and paste it into gimp and from there i can save it to my desktop or any other folder/location.

Thanks for your help, not sure what causes the problem but it's a nasty problem.