# Forcing a Partial Upgrade

Tags: updates, update-manager, partial-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrade manager wants me to do a partial upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16494/upgrade-manager-wants-me-to-do-a-partial-upgrade)

I updated to 12.04 yesterday. While it was updating however it crashed.

I restarted my computer and update manager asked to perform a Partial upgrade. This is not the first time this happened so I said yes. However the partial update also failed. I then had to leave so I turned the computer off, figuring that it'd ask me for another attempt.

However upon opening update manager I don't have the option to do a partial update (or any update whatsoever). Some of my programs are acting up and crashing - so I assume its not updated completely (new Unity works, Hud works, just some things crash)

I already tried sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install -f - but nothing happened (except asking to remove 200 mb of files).

Is there a way for me to 'force' it to partial upgrade? I don't want to format if I don't have to.