# How to recover from a partial system upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, 12.10

When I was given the option to Upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 I did try to Upgrade, but while it was upgrading the internet connection was lost and the system went through a partial upgrade.
Now when I try to open the Update  Manager or the Software Sources it opens and crashes automatically.

What should I do?

Comment: this may help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/16494/upgrade-manager-wants-me-to-do-a-partial-upgrade

Comment: and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1343434

Comment: have you tried the command: (in a terminal) `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as stated [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/16498/10698) ?

Comment: What do you do after the partial upgrade (my current situation)

Comment: you try to complete the upgrade so you get a working 12.04. It's always better to make a fresh install when something like this happens, with a fresh install you wont get any errors or slow performance. My 11.10 broke and now it takes 3 minutes to boot up.

Comment: I have no idea what a fresh install is moreover my update manager is screwed or not crashing as it opens

Comment: with a fresh install I mean that you should install Ubuntu from a live-CD and simply just remove your current installation and start from scratch. reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: The CD is something i dont have

Comment: why can't I stream videos online

Answer (score 5):

When *package* upgrades are interrupted in midway, normally doing `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get upgrade` will save the situation, but when is a full release upgrade (jumping from a version to another) the steps becomes more tricky.

What's the best solution for this cases? Reinstall. If you are not capable to reinstall, you may want to continue the upgrade using `sudo update-manager-text` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (the last one you shall modify your `sources.list` from oneiric to precise, see my command at the end), but that I won't guarantee will work. Other option is `sudo do-releases-upgrade`, but you must make sure that the process is not interrupted this time around.

**To use `apt-get dist-upgrade`**

```
sudo sed s/oneiric/precise/g /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` won't try to upgrade to the next release unless you manually edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` first (and run `apt-get update`). `apt-get dist-upgrade` is a perfectly good command to run to install updates for the *currently installed* Ubuntu release including those that require new packages to be installed or currently installed packages to be removed (that's the difference between it and `apt-get upgrade`). It is, to a significant extent, a historical curiosity that it's called `dist-upgrade`; as you say, on Ubuntu it should not be used to do a release upgrade.

Comment: @EliahKagan I'm basing my answers in [this official guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html) that specifically says, *that `do-release-upgrade` is recommended than `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`*. I've used `do-release-upgrade` with ease in the past for servers upgrades (although I reckon that not desktop) but reading more into it, seems that the `update-manager` do the same that `apt-get dist-upgrade` so it may worth a shot. Also, I had this problem once (not crashing but the upgrade simply don't go) when long history short I had to reinstall, which is not the...

Comment: solution OP wants/could do. I could add the use of `update-manager-text` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` as alternative, but I don't have any experience that those solves midway upgrades.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with using `do-release-upgrade` in this situation (provided that the goal is to upgrade from one release to another). You are totally right that `do-release-upgrade` is the correct way to upgrade from an earlier Ubuntu release to a later release, from the command-line. (Not for anything else, though.) The only point I'm making here is that `apt-get dist-upgrade` is perfectly appropriate for many uses (uses *other* than upgrading to a new release), and that since running it doesn't attempt an upgrade without an edit to `sources.list`, it's generally quite safe to run.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced a similar problem with my old laptop. I tried most of the suggestions above but kept coming with the same "partial upgrade" problem which when you run it fails giving other permissions/upgrade errors.

After many attempts I decided to give synaptic package manager a try. I chose the option for custom filters - then the option for "marked changes" and found one linux header marked as upgradable. Immediately upgraded the package which went smoothly. Then reloaded synaptic again and went down the same options in custom filters - this time I chose the option "upgradable(upstream). Found more packages that had failed in the upgrade and upgraded those. 
Reloaded synaptic once more and this time around synaptic found fewer packages that needed upgrading. After upgrading the last few packages I rebooted and everything went on smooth from there. Hope this helps someone.