# Can I upgrade to another desktop environment?

Tags: gnome, upgrade

I'm currently running a Vanilla Ubuntu 12.04 LTS that had Unity replaced with with gnome-shell.  What I'd like to do is to do a `do-release-upgrade` that will install a specific flavor of Ubuntu (GNOME in this case) in 12.10?

I'd like to avoid doing upgrades that bring Unity back in, forcing me to clear it out again.

Comment: This wasn't meant to be a version skip question but an Ubuntu flavor skip question.  I tried to clarify the question a bit more.

Comment: What you're asking for is probably possible, but it will not involve `do-release-upgrade`. Any use of `do-release-upgrade` except to upgrade an earlier version of Ubuntu to a later one is unsupported and likely to fail and break things badly.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite complicated, and there isn't an easy/quick way to do this. The best approach is to completely remove unity, install gnome3, then upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get purge unity unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-services unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications gir1.2-unity-5.0 unity-common indicator-sound indicator-power indicator-appmenu libindicator7 indicator-application indicator-datetime indicator-messages libnux-2.0-0 nux-tools libunity-misc4 unity-2d-common lightdm
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop ubuntu-gnome-default-settings
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I recommend you to do this in a text based environment, since the GUI binaries could be incomplete leaving the desktop unstable.

If you want to force unity to be uninstalled, you can put the package on hold:

```
echo 'unity hold' | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

I'm not totally sure that `do-release-upgrade` respect on hold packages, due the lack of documentation.

Comment: `do-release-upgrade` is totally wrong (and dangerous) here, though not for reasons relating to held packages. `do-release-upgrade` will try to actually upgrade to the next Ubuntu release! `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` is the correct command here (but run `sudo apt-get update` first and, ideally, `sudo apt-get upgrade` as well). This relates to [my comment there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150791/partial-upgrade-on-12-04/333364#comment424480_333364). Counter-intuitively, `dist-upgrade` is correct here *because* you are not attempting to upgrade to a subsequent version of Ubuntu.