# "About this computer" shows 15.04 after update to 15.10

Tags: 15.10

About this computer still shows 15.04, while /etc/os-release shows 15.10 after updating.

> $ cat /etc/os-release 
>   NAME="Ubuntu" 
>   VERSION="15.10 (Wily Werewolf)" 
>   ID=ubuntu 
>   ID_LIKE=debian 
>   PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 15.10" 
>   VERSION_ID="15.10" 
>   HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/" 
>   SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/" 
>   BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"

[About this computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip1EE.png) 
Is this just an annoyance or a sign of a lurking problem?

Comment: It's an annoyance. The About uses a graphic that doesn't get updated. This has also been asked several times before if you search around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue for me.  The next day, I got a message informing me to do a "Partial Upgrade".  Instructions for addressing this message can be found here:

[Partial Upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16494/upgrade-manager-wants-me-to-do-a-partial-upgrade?lq=1)