# GNU GRUB version 2.04 partial update

Tags: boot, grub2, updates, gnu

I partially updated my laptop from 18.04 to 20.04 and after the last update, and restarting my laptop I am met with this GNU GRUB 2.04 screen.

I get a couple errors after hitting enter to start the highlighted Ubuntu option.
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'.
error: you need to load the kernel fist.

I checked the command
grub> ls (hd0)
Devise hd0: no known file system detected - sector size - total size [does it matter how many bits I have?]

I checked the command
grub> ls (hd0,msdos1s)
Partition hd0,msdos1s: Filesystem type ext* - Last modification time 2020-11-04 19:42:25 Wednesday, UUID [do you need to know this 32 digit string of letters and numbers?] - Partition start at 1024Kib - total size [same bit bit].

I'm thinking of trying to set the root to hd0,msdos1s

Should I try this?

Comment: How did you *partially* update from 18.04 to 20.04?  Was the upgrade unsuccessful?

Comment: I selected the "partial update" option since I couldn't update for reasons unknown to me. I suspect it may be because I was unable to update my repository for several months and didn't seek to resolve that issue earlier. However the partial update from 18.04 to 20.04 worked well for a few weeks up until now.

Comment: If you encountered [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16494/upgrade-manager-wants-me-to-do-a-partial-upgrade), then you already had a pre-existing problem. An attempt to upgrade an already broken system is usually only going to make things worse.  My suggestion now that you have accumulated several issues is to cleanly reinstall 20.04.  Because even if you fix this problem, you will still need to fix the other problems that you ignored when you agreed to continue with a partial upgrade.

Comment: Yes I did encounter that. Would it still be possible for me to try and back up my latest info from the broken system then reinstall?

Comment: If you can mount the file system you can access data from a live session