# Ubuntu 20.04: Stuck at partial upgrade

Tags: server, kubuntu, update-manager, partial-upgrade

I have upgraded the Ubuntu from the version 18 to 20.04. After upgrading I have tried to update the software's but it was asking me to do a partial update so I have started it but its almost 8 hours still its loading/running.

I tried to quit it but its telling I should not do it. Please suggest.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Something was corrupted or wrong with your sources to get that error/notification to begin with.  If your system has been stuck for 8 hrs you don't have a choice except to interrupt. But that doesn't mean that everything will be OK. You will either need to discover the source(s) of the original problem or reinstall broken software.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16494/upgrade-manager-wants-me-to-do-a-partial-upgrade

Comment: Have you tried to maximize the terminal part of upgrade window? It may ask you a question in text mode...

Comment: @N0rbert I cannot maximize the terminal but in the terminal its showing "mysqld is running as pid 12156"

Comment: @Nmath Can I quit and restart the system. Will that cause any issue?

Comment: You already had an issue.  And yes, interrupting the updates can cause more problems, but if it's been stuck for 8 hrs you don't really have a choice

Comment: NEVER do Partial Upgrades. They usually break the system. Reinstall 20.04.